# can't select username from database table and display it

Tags: php, syntax-error

i'm just trying to get username from database table and upload the file into the folder named with username  but it gives me an error. this is the error : `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/u381071273/public_html/upload/upload.php on line 18`but  i can't find it. i want to get username from database table and display it where i put `&username`

code:

```
require("models/db-settings.php");
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT user_name FROM upl_users");

// This will move the internal pointer and skip the first row, we don't want that.
//$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
//echo $row['user_name'];

while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
echo $row['user_name'];}
$dir = "uploads/".$row['user_name']."/";

if (file_exists($UploadedDirectory)) {

mkdir('uploads/".$row['user_name']."/', 0777, true);

}
if(isset($_FILES["FileInput"]) && $_FILES["FileInput"]["error"]== UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
{
############ Edit settings ##############
$UploadDirectory    = 'uplaods/".$row['user_name']."/'; //specify upload    directory ends with / (slash)
##########################################

/*
Note : You will run into errors or blank page if "memory_limit" or "upload_max_filesize" is set to low in "php.ini". 
Open "php.ini" file, and search for "memory_limit" or "upload_max_filesize" limit 
and set them adequately, also check "post_max_size".
*/

//check if this is an ajax request
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])){
    die();
}


//Is file size is less than allowed size.
if ($_FILES["FileInput"]["size"] > 5242880) {
    die("File size is too big!");
}

//allowed file type Server side check
switch(strtolower($_FILES['FileInput']['type']))
    {
        //allowed file types
        case 'image/png': 
        case 'image/gif': 
        case 'image/jpeg': 
        case 'image/pjpeg':
        case 'text/plain':
        case 'text/html': //html file
        case 'application/x-zip-compressed':
        case 'application/pdf':
        case 'application/msword':
        case 'application/vnd.ms-excel':
        case 'video/mp4':
        case 'audio/mp3';
            break;
        default:
            die('Unsupported File!'); //output error
}

$File_Name          = strtolower($_FILES['FileInput']['name']);
$File_Ext           = substr($File_Name, strrpos($File_Name, '.')); //get file    extention
$Random_Number      = uniqid(); //Random number to be added to name.
$NewFileName        = $Random_Number.$File_Ext; //new file name

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FileInput']['tmp_name'],    $UploadDirectory.$NewFileName ))
   {
    die('Success! File Uploaded.');
}else{
    die('error uploading File!');
}

}
else
{
die('Something wrong with upload! Is "upload_max_filesize" set correctly?');
}
```

Comment: `mkdir("uploads/".$row['user_name']."/", 0777, true);` please tell me this is outside of the document root or at least in a folder that's protected by .htaccess and locked down by IP address ... something.

Comment: its simply in public_html/upload/ , and there no .htaccess file yet

Comment: ... so you're making a world + dog, readable, writeable and executable directory available to the aforementioned world + dog and helpfully naming the sub-directories as valid site usernames ... this feels a little like the Swiss Cheese of security to me (it's full of holes).

Comment: hard to say exactly - if the `/upload` folder doesn't need to be accessible over http move it outside the document root or put an `.htaccess` file containing *Deny from all* to prevent access to it - and don't use 777 permissions - 770 might do it (though that's still as vulnerable as the application). Disguise the 'username' folders (perhaps naming them with a hash) so that it reduces the attack vector on the database - the problem with security is that there's rarely a *one size fits all" solution and you have to evaluate the risks against the functionality on a case by case basis.

Comment: i have added deny from all and it working fine and protects the files inside models which contains db information and config.php

Answer (score 3):

```
mkdir('uploads/".$row['user_name']."/', 0777, true);
```

Should be:

```
mkdir('uploads/'.$row['user_name'].'/', 0777, true);
```

(You used different string anchors when doing the concatenation - started string with `'` but tried to close it with `"`)

Comment: Ha same answer I am deleting mine :-)

Comment: admin Warning: move_uploaded_file(uplaods//530735df8e5a4.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u381071273/public_html/upload/upload.php on line 70 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpJq2NsR' to 'uplaods//530735df8e5a4.jpg' in /home/u381071273/public_html/upload/upload.php on line 70 error uploading File!

Comment: There is `uploads` and you have `uplaods` @ArshSingh

Comment: array(1) { ["user_name"]=> string(5) "admin" }

Comment: its ok now , but its uploading file without making folder inside 'uploads', it uplaods file inside uploads without making folder named with surrent user

Comment: Do an "echo $row['user_name'];" so check if it gets a value. It could be that it returns an emtpy string.

Comment: Try `mkdir("uploads/".$row['user_name'], 0777, true);` and without the `'/'` see if that will make it work. @ArshSingh

Comment: not working same : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/u381071273/public_html/upload/upload.php on line 18

Answer (score 1):

use this line:( you can use single quotes  or double quotes dont mix)

```
mkdir("uploads/".$row['user_name']."/", 0777, true);
```

Comment: working but main problem is that code is not making a folder inside : `uploads` named with `username` i just want to get username from database and make the folder with that name